Can I use my Japanese Passport to travel outside in the Philippines and returning back to the Philippines?
I was born and raised in the Philippines and I also possess Japanese passport but I am living in the Philippines since birth. I have a PH passport but it was already expired. I was about to renew my Philippine passport but I was denied in doing so because I can’t possess both passport since I am already 28 years old. My problem is if I am planning to travel abroad exiting in the Philippines and returning also in the Philippines will there be a problem to enter in the Philippines using my Japanese passport?

Have you checked about the dual nationality?  The Philippines used to not accept dual nationality after 18 but they do now.  I know people who have reacquired Philippine nationality while retaining another nationality.

For dual national citizens making a short visit to the Philippines, it is actually cheaper to not use their Filipino passport as, on leaving, they would need to pay an exit tax with their Filipino passport.  I am not posting an answer since I don't know anyone in your situation and it is hard to extrapolate.

If you travel on your Japanse passport you might have issues returning to the Philippines, check whether that will be an issue for you.

Your actual issue is not the passports, it's citizenship.
According to my (very limited) understanding, the Philippines allows dual citizenship, but it has to be explicitly applied for.  If you were denied a Philippine passport, this suggests you have not done this and that the Philippines considers you a Japanese citizen only. Which also means that you are technically an illegal immigrant at the moment!
What you need to do, then, is to collect the necessary evidence that you're a natural-born Filipino citizen and make an appointment to pledge allegiance.  Here's the rules for how to do this in New York, I'm sure there something similar in the Philippines themselves. Once you have completed this, you can apply for a Philippine passport and travel in and out of the country freely.
One important warning: Japan does not allow dual citizenship for adults, and in theory pledging allegiance to the Phils as an adult cancels your Japanese citizenship. In practice, though, they don't really care, although you may need to jump through hoops to keep renewing your Jp passport, typically by traveling to Japan to do it.
